# How to call a modal dialog (with HTML file) from a sidebar (also HTML) with google scripts

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, materialize

I need a little light on how to make some buttons work.

I have a sidebar created on a HTML file that called from a button inside a spreadsheet on google apps. here's the function:

```
function Sidebar() {
  var Form = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Sidebar");
  var ShowForm = Form.evaluate();

  ShowForm.setTitle("Sidebar");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ShowForm);
}
```

And here's my Sidebar.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
     <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize-icons.css">      
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
     </head>

    <!--WELCOME CARD-->

    <body style="background-color:#424242">
    <div class="card grey darken-2" style="top:3px">
        <div class="card-content white-text">
          <span class="card-title" style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;color:#80cbc4">MANAGER</span>
          <p style="font-size:14px">Welcome to the manager, choose an option below to start!</p>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!--BUTTONS-->

    <div class="fixed-action-btn" style="bottom: 45px; right: 10px;">
       <a class="btn-floating btn-large teal">START</a>
       <ul>
          <li><a class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light teal darken-3 tooltipped" id= "btn1" data-position="left" data-tooltip="Button 1"><i class="material-icons">format_list_numbered</i></a></li>
          <li><a class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light teal darken-3 tooltipped" id= "btn2" data-position="left" data-tooltip="Button 2"><i class="material-icons">assessment</i></a></li>
          <li><a class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light teal darken-3 tooltipped" id= "btn3" data-position="left" data-tooltip="Button 3"><i class="material-icons">search</i></a></li>
          <li><a class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light teal darken-3 tooltipped" id= "btn4" data-position="left" data-tooltip="Button 4"><i class="material-icons">add_box</i></a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tooltipped').tooltip();
    $('.fixed-action-btn').floatingActionButton();
  });
  </script>

    </body>
  </html>
```

I have all the buttons created (it's a fixed action button that reveals 4 more actual button) and visually working, but i don't know how to make each one of them call a new html.file for a modal dialog.. I have written the functions for each button on my .gs file but can't make the actual buttons call those functions. That's my whole .gs file:

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */


function Sidebar() {
  var Form = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Sidebar");
  var ShowForm = Form.evaluate();

  ShowForm.setTitle("Sidebar");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ShowForm);
}

function btn1(){
  var Form = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("btn1");
  var ShowForm = Form.evaluate();

  ShowForm.setTitle("btn1").setHeight(400).setWidth(1000);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(ShowForm, "btn1");
}

function btn2(){
  var Form = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("btn2");
  var ShowForm = Form.evaluate();

  ShowForm.setTitle("btn2").setHeight(400).setWidth(1000);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(ShowForm, "btn2");
}

function btn3(){
  var Form = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("btn3");
  var ShowForm = Form.evaluate();

  ShowForm.setTitle("btn3").setHeight(400).setWidth(1000);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(ShowForm, "btn3");
}

function btn4(){
  var Form = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("btn4");
  var ShowForm = Form.evaluate();

  ShowForm.setTitle("btn4").setHeight(400).setWidth(1000);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(ShowForm, "btn4");
}
```

If anyone could give some tip about how to do that, I'll be really thankfull.. thanks in advance!

- I'm using the Materialize CSS.
- My sidebar is summoned by a button on a spreadsheet.
- Some prints:
  [Sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbJzk.png) // [Buttons unfolded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Voder.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can achieve this by using `google.script.run` function.

In the following example you can see it working for just one button, but it goes the same for all of them.

```js
/* Code.gs */

function Sidebar() {
  var Form = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Sidebar");
  var ShowForm = Form.evaluate();

  ShowForm.setTitle("Sidebar");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ShowForm);
}

function btn1(){
  // Display a modal dialog box with custom HtmlService content.
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
  .createHtmlOutput('<p>My modal content here...</p>')
  .setWidth(250)
  .setHeight(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Btn 1 modal title');
}
```

You want the function `btn1` to be called when the icon of `btn1` is clicked in the sidebar.
To do this and still use the materialize icons, you can change the `<input>` tags for `<button>` and place the icon inside as follows:

```html
<!-- Sidebar.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<!--WELCOME CARD-->

<body style="background-color:#424242">
    <div class="card grey darken-2" style="top:3px">
        <div class="card-content white-text">
            <span class="card-title" style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;color:#80cbc4">MANAGER</span>
            <p style="font-size:14px">Welcome to the manager, choose an option below to start!</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--BUTTONS-->

    <div class="fixed-action-btn" style="bottom: 45px; right: 10px;">
        <a class="btn-floating btn-large teal">START</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <button id="btn1" data-position="left" data-tooltip="Button 1" class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light teal darken-3 tooltipped" value="format_list_numbered" onclick="google.script.run.withUserObject(this).btn1()"><i class="material-icons">format_list_numbered</i></button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.tooltipped').tooltip();
            $('.fixed-action-btn').floatingActionButton();
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Notice the button's onclick attribute**

`onclick="google.script.run.withUserObject(this).btn1()"`

---

You can use `google.script.run` to call functions in your .gs scripts from the client-side.

### Note:

You can create the htmlOutput from file too. Change the code in the `btn1` function accordingly.

```js
function btn1(){
  // Display a modal dialog box with custom HtmlService content.
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
  .createHtmlOutputFromFile('btn1')
  .setWidth(250)
  .setHeight(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Btn 1 modal title');
}
```

Here is an example of `btn1.html`

```html
<p>This is HTML generated from file...</p>
```

See it in action:

### [image]

#### Further reading:

- [Show modal Dialogs in UI](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showmodaldialoguserinterface,-title)
- [Apps Script HTML service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html)

Comment: There's anything I have to change on the onclick attribute? I've switched my button for yours, and add the function in the .gs file but still nothing happenned when I click the button..

Comment: It is probably your `btn1` function. notice it is different than yours. As you did not provide the btn1.html template

Comment: Here's what I did: in your btn1 function i've changed: ".createHtmlOutput('<p>My modal content here...</p>')" to ".createHtmlOutputFromFile("btn1")" and then created a btn1.html file. I've assigned a button in the spreadsheet to this function to test it and it run correctly. I'ts just when I try to call it from the button in the sidebar that it doesn't work.. any idea why? Seems that it should be working fine..

Comment: You likely have error in your btn1.html. Check the JS console in your browser inspector for the error message. I added to the answer so you can see it rendered from file in action. Remember to accept the answer if it works for you, and upvote if you find it useful. thanks

Comment: Every time I click in the button I get "PERMISSION_DENIED" in the browser console, so I've tried to remove the permission on the google account settings, so I could authorize again, but even when I did, still get the same error in the console.. have no clue of what's going on kkkk

Comment: Found the problem, the google account i'm using is corporative, looks like there's a bug in this cases. I've created the same project in an personal account then set the coorporative account as proprietary and it works like a charm! Can't thank you enough man, you rock!

Answer (score 0):

Try `google.script.run.AnyServerSideFunctionName()`

[Client to Server Communications](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)